# Unable to run Async Method without Console.ReadLine() Or Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#, console.readline

I have my main method calling another method. Everything works fine as long as I use `Console.Readline()` or `Console.ReadKey()`. The minute I remove it, the project is finishing without doing completely what it is supposed to do.

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var SQLServerName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net";
    var SQLServerAdmin = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var SQLServerAdminPasword = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var DatabaseName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    string SQLStatement = ($"TRUNCATE TABLE XXXXXXXXXXXX" + 
                           $"TRUNCATE TABLE XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    Helper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword, DatabaseName, SQLStatement);

    List<string> Subscriptions = Helper.GetSubscriptionList();
    foreach (string Subscription in Subscriptions)
    {
        string SubscriptionID = Subscription.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        Runner(SubscriptionID);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async void Runner(string SubscriptionID)
{
   var task = await RBACSnapshot.GetRBACSnapshot(SubscriptionID);   
}
```

Comment: But when I publish the project in azure functions, I need to remove the  Console.ReadKey(); right. then will the project do what it is supposed do?

Comment: You are calling an async method without the await keyword "Runner"

Comment: What @Sameer said

Comment: Now I changed the Runner Method to public static void Runner. Still no luck. WHat should i do to get rid of Console.ReadKey(

Comment: @Knoop. Tried your thing but this is making the Runner Method go in synchronous mode. I need Runner to fireoff asynchronously on each subscription.